Blazor 8 WebApp - Client Project Fails when adding Project Reference to Class Library
I am using the new Blazor 8 (.net 8.0) WebApp template with Identity Authentication and Server & WebAssembly interactive render modes.
I created an external class library for my Services that house both the Server and Client Services.   Client calls into an internal api and the Server calls into my Repositories.
However, when I add the Services project to the Client via a Project reference, my Client project fails to build with the following error

There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RunTimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm' in file Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets line 491

Anyone know why this is failing?
I have the following nuGet packages installed in the Services project:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
Newtonsoft.Json


This question is similar to: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

(Note--be sure to read through all the answers, not just the accepted one)
